# What is the javascript formula to calculate this x,y position?

Tags: javascript, math

I have a rotated rectangle in which I need to figure out how to calculate the coordinates of x2 and y2 after rotating the rectangle by -17deg.

What would be the javascript formula to calculate that coordinate?

[image: what is the javascript formula to calculate x2, y2]

Comment: This sounds like a math question more than anything else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find vertices of rectangle after rotating it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261388/find-vertices-of-rectangle-after-rotating-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86755/how-to-calculate-corner-marks-of-a-rotated-rectangle):

```js
var w = 800;
var h = 500;
var x = 0 - w / 2;
var y = 0 + h / 2;
var angle = -17;

var newX = x*Math.cos(angle) - y*Math.sin(angle);
var newY = x*Math.sin(angle) + y*Math.cos(angle);

console.log(newX, newY);
```

Answer (score 2):

If i am remembering right. You first have to calculate the center-point of the rectangle: (cx & cy = center of square coordinates)

- tempX = x-cx
- tempX = x-cy

then you can use the rotation formula: (theta =

- rotatedX = tempX * cos(theta) - tempY * sin(theta);
- rotatedY = tempX * sin(theta) + tempY * cos(theta);

In the end you can transform back the point:

- x = rotatedX + cx;
- y = rotatedY + cy;